# How to keep my audio from overlapping

Tags: android, audio

I have a simple listview with the name of some songs.  When you click on one of the childs, the song plays.  However, I noticed that when you accidentally tap it again while its playing, it start to play again causing the sounds to overlap.  How can I set it up so that when you click on one song and then click on another song, the first song stop and the second song begins.  How can I modify my code to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
                        public class TwelveGrammar extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView lv;
private MediaPlayer mp;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.twelve_grm);



    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Exp_list);

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                long id) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                mp.stop();

            }

            else {
            if (pos==0) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1200);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==1) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1201);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();

                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==2) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1202);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==3) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1203);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }


            if (pos==4) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1204);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });
            }

            if (pos==5) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1205);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==6) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1206);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==7) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1207);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==8) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1208);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==9) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1209);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==10) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1210);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==11) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1211);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==12) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1212);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }

            if (pos==13) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1213);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }
               if (pos==14) {

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1214);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        }
                });

            }
      if (pos==15) {

mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.g_1215);
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
        }
});

        }
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you want the user to be able to start playback of another song while a song already is playing (stopping the current song at the same time). Then why is the `MediaPlayer` creation code in the `else`-clause for `if (isPlaying())`? And you really should get rid of all those unnecessary `if`-statements, as they're all essentially identical. Put your sound resource IDs in some sort of array and use `pos` to index the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have one boolean like `boolean isAnotherSongPlaying` and if it's true the previous song should be stopped and the new one should start. And I believe that the best way to handle mediaplayer is a Service. I'm not yet too familiarized with that but I have implemented a Service for background music and its control depending on user's actions and it works quite well.

**MyService.class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);// raw/s.mp3
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
  }


  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
  }

  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
    stopSelf();
  }

}
```

in my **main activity** I have one button which starts and stops the service depending whether the music is playing or not

```
Intent play;
play = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
```

...

```
sound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPlaying){
                stopService(play);
                isPlaying = false;
                sound.setText("Yes");
            } else {
                startService(play);
                isPlaying = true;
                sound.setText("No");
            }
        }
    });
```

Search it also on google you'll find some good tutorials. Hope I helped you.